# Gnucash imported QIF file not working the same as Quicken - all debits

Tags: gnucash, qif

Good morning:
I am a first time poster, long time user of gnucash...

I am trying to import a QIF file into gnucash. Gnucash is entering everything as a debit. I can't verify this but am being told that it works with Quicken. Is there a problem with the file or is there a problem with gnucash? I would appreciate any help.

Here is the qif file (I didn't see an option for an attachment)

!Type:Cash

D06/10'23

U0.00

T0.00

PCustomer1

MCottage #3 Bkg 1032 06/10/2023-06/17/2023

L

SIncome:Cottage Rental:Cottage #3

ECottage #3 Bkg 1032 06/10/2023-06/17/2023

$1075.00

SIncome:HST Collected

ECottage #3 Bkg 1032 HST

$139.75

SAssets:TD Business

ECottage #3 Bkg 1032 06/10/2023-06/17/2023

$-1214.75

^

D06/10'23

U1214.75

T1214.75

PCustomer1

MCottage #3 Bkg 1032 Payment etransfer

L

SAssets:TD Business

ECottage #3 Bkg 1032 Payment etransfer

$1214.75

^